# Проблема с добавлением класса в jquery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь добавить класс уже к существующему:

```
$('.point-block#p1').addClass('active');
```

Затем пытаюсь вызвать его:

```
$('.point-block.active .point').bind('click',function() { ...
```

Эффект нулевой. При этом нужно заметить, когда я изначально в html пишу .point-block.active, т.е. без добавление через jquery, то все работает. Не могу понять в чем причина ошибки, раньше с такими ошибками не сталкивался.

Смотрел код, там все ок: после добавление класса выглядит примерно так -

```
<div id="p1" class="point-block active"><div class="point"></div><div class="number"></div></div>
```

Comment: Я не очень понимаю вашу терминологию. Что значит "вызвать класс"? Давайте порешаем всё на jsfiddle или jsbin?

Comment: [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/fVcan/), что не так работает?

Comment: почему бы не

    var element=$('.point-block#p1').addClass('active');
    element.find('.point').bind('click',function(e){...});

Answer (score 2):

Вы ошибаетесь, все работает.
[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xghxG/)

Почему-то уверен, что обработчик Вы пытаетесь повесить перед тем, как добавляете клас...

Вот так будет работать, даже если класс добавляется позже:

```
$('body').on('click', '.point-block.active .point', function() {alert('!')});
```

[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xghxG/1/)

Comment: разве делегирование событий через body не то же самое что и метод .live()?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
$('.point-block.active .point').on('click',function() { ...
```

или даже

```
$('.point-block.active .point').live('click',function() { ...
```

Comment: К сожалению, ни то, ни то, не работает. проверял